# Google Analytics Query Explorer won't take inputs

Tags: user-interface, google-analytics

I am very familiar with `GA Query Explorer` (https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/).

Just yesterday and today its UI has begun to refuse to key input.  When I try to type in the `metrics` or `dimensions` fields it gives a message 'No matches found' - see screenshot.  It has therefore become utterly useless.

I tried removing all GA cookies and logging out.  I closed my Firefox browser, where I have used it regularly.  On return I logged into Google and opened a Query Explorer tab.  It remembered my latest parameters, so it had not removed cookies, and duly gave the same error.

Can you please advise how I can get out of this vicious circle and begin to get results from the Query Explorer again?

[image: screenshot of error message]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem too. I believe there is a problem on the page, probably due to this error in the console:

[image]

I report the bug here:

https://github.com/googleanalytics/ga-dev-tools/issues/461

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to responders.

This has now been fixed by Google.

Graham